# Need to call a activity in PhoneStateListener

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I need to call a activity when the phone state comes from ringing to idle. But It says **The constructor Intent(MyPhoneStateListener, Class) is undefined**. How can call the activity.

```
    public class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
        //static String org="";

        public void onCallStateChanged(int state,String incomingNumber){
              switch(state){
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                  Log.d("DEBUG", "IDLE");
                 // MissedCall ms=new MissedCall();

                 Intent missintent=new Intent(this,MissedCall.class);
                 startActivity(missintent);

                break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                  Log.d("DEBUG", "OFFHOOK");
                break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                  Log.d("DEBUG", "RINGING");
                break;
                }
              }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call the activity like this:

```
Intent missintent= new Intent(context, MissedCall.class);
missintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(missintent);
```

Comment: Thanks Vineet. But it says "The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type MyPhoneStateListener".

Comment: put the MyPhoneStateListener class in the service...check this:http://lovingandroid.blogspot.com/2011/07/intercept-call-activity.html

Comment: Though I put the MyPhoneStateListener class in service, I got the same error.

Comment: I didn't run the app. After entering the code it shows error in the IDE itself.

Comment: Thanks Vineet. It works with a little change in the code.     
context.startActivity(missintent);

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem (as Manikandan), Eclipse tell me that  "The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type MyPhoneStateListener" is it possible to fire an intent in an other way ?

Comment: This works......Intent missintent= new Intent(context, MissedCall.class);
missintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(missintent);

Answer (score 0):

Note that your MyPhoneStateListener class must be defined within an Activity class, otherwise there is no context from which to launch an activity.